# How can I skin / theme a windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, html, css, winforms

I need to create a windows forms application that users can customize the styles of forms easy and flexible, also my application need access to registry and system files. 
how can i do it? is there a better way (using html and css)?

Comment: @JesonPark: Most of the users don't know WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than a few third party libraries that allow WinForms Skinning / Themeing, such as [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/), there isn't much you can do. And no, you cannot use HTML and CSS, you'll need to be developing a WinRT Win8 app to use HTML for the UI.

Answer (score 0):

To make rich user interfaces use  WPF with Themes, for extra sexy looks use devexpress controls together with WPF

Comment: Or just build a website, and load that website into your browser control in your windows forms app.

Comment: So how can I handle the web page events (like clicking a button)?